# Adding a child with a specified name in Firebase Database Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I am building a Xamarin Forms app with the help of firebase's realtime database.  When I store data in the database like this:

```
  public static async Task AddPerson(string name, string Email)
    {

        await firebase
          .Child("Users")
          .PostAsync(new Person() { Name = name, Email = Email});
         
    }
```

The database stores the values nested under the "Users", and under some randomly generated id (Example: "-MTOFu5dMzjcVdWFwiBt").  How do I write code that will instead name it based on the person's Email, so that I can use this in my query to find the data nested under it? Thank you!

EDIT:  I also define "firebase" as the FirebaseClient in an earlier line of code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `PostAsync` Firebase generates the key automatically. To specify your own name, use `PutAsync` and specify the child to update in another child call:

```
firebase
  .Child("Users")
  .Child("KeyOfUsertoUpdate")
  .PutAsync(new Person() { Name = name, Email = Email});
```

Note that Firebase Realtime Database keys cannot contains a dot `.` character, so you can't use the email address one-on-one. If you want to use it, a common approach is replace dots in the email address with a comma `,`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Worked perfectly :)